# handle value by reactor with stream

Tags: java

I just want to do something like this by reactor

```
Object value=1;
List<Consumer>consumers=new ArrayList();
consumers.add(xx) ..... 

for (Consumer c : consumers)
{
     if(c.consumer(value)){ // dosomething}
     else return 
}
```

How could i implement this by the reactive

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromIterable` to create a `Flux` that emits each element from the iterable list:

```
   Flux.fromIterable(consumers)
```

and `takeWhile` to relay consumers while your predicate returns true:

```
Flux.fromIterable(consumers)
        .takeWhile(c -> <your predicate>)
        .flatMap(c -> dosomethingAsync())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thx,I will take a try